Pywinauto, print_control_identifiers not displaying the chrome print windows UI elements
I am in a similar situation as this post . I am using selenium to access a webpage, navigate to a specific page and then click on a link that opens the print dialog.
I am planning on then connecting to the print dialog using pywinauto to set up the printing options and print de document, but I am having trouble locating the UI elements in the print dialog.
When I use Inspect.exe, I can locate the elements just fine, but when I execute my code that connects to the already opened crome window and then print I am unable to locate the ui elements.

When executing the following code:
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re=".*- Google Chrome -.*")


win = app.window(best_match="using pywinauto, how can I draw a rectangle arround a ui element?")
win.print_control_identifiers()

The control identifiers do not display anything that looks remotely similar to the ui elements I need to access.
The most I have been able to locate in the control identifiers tree is the following:
   | Pane - 'Print'    (L299, T78, R1622, B955)
   | ['Print', 'PrintPane', 'Pane22']
   | child_window(title="Print", control_type="Pane")
   |    | 
   |    | Pane - ''    (L299, T78, R1622, B955)
   |    | ['Pane23']
   |    |    |
   |    |    | Pane - ''    (L299, T78, R1622, B955)
   |    |    | ['Pane24']
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    | ['Pane25']
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L306, T83, R1615, B946)
   |    |    |    | ['Pane26']

Which seems to have something to do with the Print dialog, but I can't locate anything that looks like any of the drop-downs I need to interact with.
Any pointers will be greatly appreciated since I have been strugling with this for days.
